# onChange function did not return the target value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create onChange function for TextArea component but somehow it didn't update the state when using console.log or even pass it to the payload. And when I use JSON.stringify the value is update to the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should write handler functions like below:

```
onChange={() => handleChangeModalWorkflow("note")}
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: thanks, but not working as well